# HTML5 / Javascript Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

Im getting started with the web audio API and for som reason this code only play the oscillator one time, what am I missing?

```
    <select class="osc1">
        <option value = "sawtooth">Sawtooth</option>
        <option value = "square">Square</option>
        <option value = "triangle">Triangle</option>
        <option value = "sine">Sine</option>
    </select>
    <button id="play-btn">Play</button>

    <script>
        var ac = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        function createOsc(ac, elclass)
        {
            var osc = ac.createOscillator();
            osc.frequency.value = 110;
            osc.type = document.getElementsByClassName(elclass)[0].value;
            osc.connect(ac.destination);

            osc.start();
            osc.stop(2);
        }

        document.getElementById("play-btn").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            createOsc(ac, 'osc1');
        });
    </script>
```

**SOLUTION**

I managed to find the solution by myself, when calling the method stop it expects as argument the context current time plus number of seconds in a floating point.

```
 osc.stop(ac.currentTime + 2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code is working fine. I tested, it works multiple times.

What plugin are you using to play sound?

(Sorry, couldn't comment because of my low reputation)

Comment: That's weird, i've tested in Chrome and Firefox it only plays the first created oscillator. I'm not using any plugin. It's just vanilla Javascript and the Web Audio API documented in MDN, which doesnt require any plugin or library that i know. Thanks by the reply

Comment: Could you tell in which browser you've tested it? and which version? thanks